# How to direct Apache2 HTTPS sub-directory request to HTTP app server on another port?

Tags: https, apache2, http, reverse-proxy

for complete Apache newbie, I have NextCloud and Monitorix running on my local server

```
https://192.168.1.2/nextcloud
http://192.168.1.2:8080/monitorix
```

and I would like to cover it via SSL, something like 1)

```
https://192.168.1.2/monitorix
```

or it could run on a different port, does not matter 2)

```
https://192.168.1.2:8443/monitorix
```

What to add/modify in apache2 configuration to do it?

**Remarks**:

- Nextcloud has its own files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`
- Monitorix standard install is probably using its own app/web server, not apache.

Comment: Do you have a domain name?  HTTPS doesn't usually work with IP address URLs.  You can't get a certificate for a private IP address like `192.168.1.2`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419568/accessing-https-sites-with-ip-address and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name

Comment: actually, no domain name so far, only internal network at this time.

Comment: So you are currently using a self-signed cert on your Apache server for HTTPS?

Comment: I removed the word "redirect" from your title and tags.   A redirect changes the URL.  If you redirect a HTTPS URL to the HTTP URL, the visitor will still see the HTTP URL in the address bar.   I don't think that is what you want.

Comment: @Stephen, yes just self signed certificates this time..